# ASP.NET MVC4 with EF 6 Model Update Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two models as below

```
public class Category
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int ID { get; set; },
     [Required]
     public string category { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string Desc { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int ID { get; set; },
     public int CatID { get; set; },
     [ForeignKey("CatID")]
     public virtual Category Category { get; set; },
     [Required]
     public string Desc { get; set; },
     public string DisplayName
     {
         get
         {
             return string.format("{0} - {1}",this.Category.category,this.Desc);
         }
     }
}
```

This is my Edit Action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     ViewBag.PossibleCategories = categoryRepository.All;
     return View(productRepository.Find(id));
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)  //<== This becomes false saying category.desc is required
     {
          productRepository.InsertOrUpdate(product);
          productRepository.Save();          
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     else
     {
          ViewBag.PossibleCategories = categoryRepository.All;
          return View();
     }
}
```

I have a scaffolded a Edit view of product and it shows ID and DisplayName as Readonly. All the other fields a editable.

The edit view also has the product -> category -> category has a read-only text field

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Category.category, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "readonly", "true" } })
```

The Post back sends this and tries to create a new category. This is not required. The category link will be carried forward using the product.CatID.

How can i display these types of fields??

<strike>When the Edit view Post back the Model state appears as invalid because the product's category's desc is null (product -> category -> desc). 
if i comment out the DisplayName property in Product this issue doesn't occur.</strike>

From my understanding, this is because the DiaplayName property refers to Category property and the view view doesn't have category.desc field so when the model is created back on the POST action, the desc is not populated. Adding the category.desc field to the view is one way of solving this problem. 
Is there any other method to solve this?

Note: This is not the only model i'm having this issue. There are many complex models which have the same problem and to me having these fields also included in the view would make for (1) a very cluttered view (2) the amount of data making the round trip will be high.

Comment: I updated my answer if you want to take a look.

Comment: thanks for the answer, had to go off the grid for a day!

Comment: as i hav commented below, i had misinterpreted the issue. I made the correction.

again @MiniRagnarok sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple Solution

Check for null. Really you should be making this a habit anyway.

```
 public string DisplayName
 {
     get
     {
         if(this.Category != null)
         {
             return string.format("{0} - {1}",this.Category.category,this.Desc);
         }
         else
         {
             return String.Empty;
         }
     }
 }
```

#### Complex Solution

Instead of directly using your database model in your Views another solution is to create ViewModels. These are models meant specifically for your View. As a simplified example, let's take your Product model and create a ViewModel.

1. Create a folder for your ViewModels
2. Create ViewModel files that match your Controller
3. Create a ViewModel that you will use in your View

Say you have a Store Controller. This would be the file structure you would create.

```
Models
    ViewModels
        StoreViewModels.cs
```

Inside the StoreViewModels you would create a ViewModel called ProductViewModel which you would fill in with information from Product.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel() { }
    public ProductViewModel(Product product)
    {
        this.ID = product.ID;
        this.Description = product.Description;
        this.DisplayName = product.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

In your View you reference ProductViewModel instead of Product. On the receiving end you then translate the ViewModel fields back to your Model. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: i'm sorry i think i may hav found the exact cause of the error (i might hav misled you in the initial question, sorry abt that)

My view has a text field for category.category
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Category.category, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "readonly", "true" } })`

this is forcing to create category entity which is not required. The category is saved via dropdown list so the catid is avaiable for Model. which keeps the link between the category and product. 
The product.Category.category field is readonly. It's there for display purpose.

i changed the above issue too.

Comment: @InsI Glad you figured it out. I still recommend the second solution. It's made my life easier in the past.

Comment: i not could get the issue sorted. But i found what's causing the problem. I need to show the field in the view. Regarding your complex solution, I did some searching and found out automapper.org which copies the data from one object to another. But i'm looking for an alternative, as there is a considerable amount of changes which need to be done to integrate this. And my timeline is not that much. Can look into this on a later sprint.